# Cannot add ubuntu to the suse grub

Tags: opensuse, dual-boot

I am running SuSE 11.2. I also have windows and Ubuntu on the same machine. The problem is that I cannot get Ubuntu to show as a boot option on SuSE's grub. The Ubuntu partition is on `/dev/sda5`. Here is my `/boot/grub/menu.lst`:

```
# Modified by YaST2. Last modification on Wed Sep 15 13:08:06 SAST 2010
# THIS FILE WILL BE PARTIALLY OVERWRITTEN by perl-Bootloader
# Configure custom boot parameters for updated kernels in /etc/sysconfig/bootloader

default 0
timeout 8
##YaST - generic_mbr
gfxmenu (hd0,2)/boot/message
##YaST - activate

###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: linux###
title Desktop -- openSUSE 11.2 - 2.6.31.12-0.2
    root (hd0,2)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31.12-0.2-desktop root=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3160815AS_9RX3KRP8-part3 resume=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3160815AS_9RX3KRP8-part2 splash=silent quiet showopts vga=0x31a
    initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.31.12-0.2-desktop

###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: failsafe###
title Failsafe -- openSUSE 11.2 - 2.6.31.12-0.2
    root (hd0,2)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31.12-0.2-desktop root=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3160815AS_9RX3KRP8-part3 showopts apm=off noresume nosmp maxcpus=0 edd=off powersaved=off nohz=off highres=off processor.max_cstate=1 x11failsafe vga=0x31a
    initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.31.12-0.2-desktop

###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: windows###
title Windows
    rootnoverify (hd0,0)
    chainloader +1

#Don’t change this comment – YaST2 identifier: Original name: none#
title Ubuntu 10.04
    root (hd0,4)
    kernel /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5 ro quiet splash
    initrd /initrd.img
```

Comment: To avoid confusion, please be explicit about what version of grub you are using, whether grub legacy or grub 2. For preference, quote the version number. The config file does look like grub legacy, but is your system running grub legacy?

Answer (score 1):

Try chainloading the version of GRUB Ubuntu ships with instead of using the same GRUB from SuSE:

```
title Ubuntu 10.04
    root (hd0,4)
    chainloader +1
```

This way Ubuntu will manage it's own GRUB configuration and kernel upgrades on it's own partition.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing that from YaST->Boot Loader->Choose Image and then fill all the other options like your kernel image etc and you are done :)

Comment: I cannot see the ubuntu options from within YaST->Boot Loader->Choose Image

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the ubuntu options are located in `/etc/grub.cfg`. It will take some parsing; that file on my system looks like a whole shell script, but  the tail end looks like you should be able to parse it out sufficiently to get what you need.

Comment: I am only able to boot from suse now so help access my ubuntu partition.

Comment: If you type `mount /dev/sda5 /mnt`(either as root or with sudo), then you should be able to access the root of your ubunto partition at /mnt.

Comment: This is a red herring, it should be the grub from SuSe running.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct. I have a few recommendations. First try taking off the `quiet splash`. Secondly I would list the full path to the kernel and initrd image.

```
title Ubuntu
    root (hd0,4)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-<ubuntu-kernel-version> root=/dev/sda5 ro
    initrd /boot/initrd-<ubuntu-kernel-version>
```

Lastly, make sure you update grub.

```
  grub --batch --device-map=/boot/grub/device.map < /etc/grub.conf
```

**Caveate:** I don't use SUSE, I found that command [here](http://www.novell.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/ch07s04.html).

Comment: You shouldn't need to update grub just because the menu/configuration has changed.  Perhaps, if the device.map needs updating because a disk was added, but grub reads it's configuration from disk on each boot unlike lilo.

Comment: @penguin359 True, but I don't know what state everything is in. Updating grub will ensure that it's correct.